# Truncating string but output returns wrong count

Tags: twig

I'm trying to create a system to truncate a string at 33 characters. But the length of some string seems to be wrong

Here an example of string :

```
"ZAC Canal Pte d’Aubervilliers"
```

Return 35 characters instead of 29.

This string is not supposed to be truncated.
The apostrophe counts as multiple characters.

I tried many filters `|raw` or `|striptags` without success.

What's wrong please ?

```
{{ project.title|length > 33 ? project.title|slice(0, 33) ~ '&hellip;' : project.title }}
```

Comment: Did you check if every characters in your string is not converted into HTML special char, like the apostrophe or that your string is correctly trimmed

Comment: Thank you for your message. It's actually a very good track. If it's in html, what should I convert it to?

Comment: I suppose you work with PHP to send the values like `project` into the twig. First you can try to `trim` it then use `html_entity_decode()` to convert the HTML special chars to the corresponfing chars

Comment: `ZAC Canal Pte d’Aubervilliers` is actually only 29 characters long... - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dm8m2l)

Comment: @Aesahaettr I used `html_entity_decode()` and now I got the good count. Thank you